# RMarkdown IO slides presentation is no longer supporting background images in the css file

Tags: r, markdown

## Creating slides with image backgrounds - the code

As recently as a few weeks ago, I was able to successfully do the following within RStudio when creating an RMarkdown file.

Rmarkdown File (the top YAML portion):

```
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: ../css/slide_style.css
    logo: ../css/logos/approved.Logos.016.jpg
    self_contained: yes
```

This would then source the css file `slide_style.css`, which contained, among other things, the following:

```
/* Below is the code to drop in a nice image for the background OUTSIDE of the slides. */
/* line 58, ../scss/default.scss */
/* line 236 of ../theme/../default.css */

body {
    background-image: url('../css/backgrounds/outside_slides.png');
}


/* Below is the code to drop in a nice image for the slide backgrounds, or "backdrop". */
/* line 170, ../scss/default.scss */
/* line 320 of ../theme/../default.css */

slides > slide.backdrop {
    background-image: url('../css/backgrounds/inside_slide.png');
}
```

This used to work, where the `inside_slide.png` file would be embedded as a background image (repeated) within the slides themselves, and the `outside_slides.png` file would be similarly embedded, but around the outside edges of the central slide.

## Embedding images no longer works - I've tried...

The rest of the css file works just fine.  I have nice effects, IMHO, that change where the titles are at, allows for levels of titling, changes how tables look, etc.  All that is still working fine.  The images themselves are not being embedded.  Explicitly, `outside_slides.png` and `inside_slides.png` images are no longer being rendered within the generated `.html` file.

### Checking file paths...

So, you might guess that the files themselves are the problem.  I have checked the file path, all is good.  In fact, I purposely messed it up, to make sure it would fail.  It failed, when the path was wrong.

### Opening the files themselves...

Maybe the files don't have what I think they have?  Nope, I can inspect the files with Preview or whatever, they look fine.  I also pointed to other image files, those cannot be viewed as a background, either.  I tried with `.png`, `.jpg`, and `.gif`.  No luck.

### Ensuring the css file can do other actions...

Maybe something is over-writing this body tag?  I tried something simple like `background-color: orange;`, and that works fine.  I changed the opacity, and that worked.  I also tried to add `!important` to the css sheet.  That did not help.  (Meaning, it worked for background-color, but not for background-image.)

It's as if something is over-riding such that `background-image` simply will not work.

I've been using RStudio for much of the testing.  Neither the presentation generated within RStudio, nor the generated `.html`, opened via a web browser, show the image.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

## Edit

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8     htmltools_0.2.6  rmarkdown_0.7.3  rsconnect_0.3.79 tools_3.1.3      yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: It works for me, could you post your `sessionInfo`?

Comment: @NicE Yes, good point.  I just edited the question to include my sessionInfo() call.  Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: This was working for me YESTERDAY, and today, boom. Gone. I tried everything Mike tried. I'm using Windows 7, R 3.2.2, RStudio 99.486 ...

Comment: Not sure what is happening. However,the first thing I would try would be to to use `!important`. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @zipp  Yes, I did try `!important`, placing it incrementally all over the place.  It didn't help or make a difference.  And again, ALL the other css code would work, it's just the images.  Thanks for the advice!  :(

Comment: can you share the generated html file?

Comment: uh, why does this have 22 upvotes? This error is not reproducible and is most likely attributed to user error. I did several tests which all worked as expected. There is no reason you cannot share a snippet of the rmd/css files or even a self-contained rmd with the necessary code from the stylesheet that we would need to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any code, I can give you a hint how I would debug it: Bring up the Developer Tools, in most browsers it's going to be <kbd>F12</kbd>. Now

1. Click on the magnifier icon to select the element that should have the `background-image` set
2. Open the "Styles" tab to check if something overwrote your `background-image` (will be displayed as <s>striked out</s> text)

[image]

Maybe you can you can prove / disprove your "overriding"-hypothesis this way.

Good luck!